# Request header field If-None-Match is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo

I am receiving the following error when posting to a REST API using     `dojo/store/JsonRest`.
I am using `"X-Requested-With": null` in order to avoid preflight request but I still receive this error.

API fully support CORS.

Any idea how can be fixed?

> Request header field If-None-Match is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

```
        var store = new JsonRest({
            target: 'https://api.xxx.com/data',
            headers: {
                "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + 'd4c72611fc43ab44a46344d907a2b96964df2c91',
                "X-Requested-With": null // no prefligh
            }
        });
        store.get('1-00').then(function (data) {
            // ok works here
            console.log('get', data)
        });
        // post request
        store.add({name:'test'}).then(function (data) {
            // error here
            console.log('add', data)
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue using `"If-None-Match": null` in the headers for `JsonRest`.

Interesting doc regarding `"If-None-Math"` can be found on [HTTP/1.1 spec](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html).

---

```
var store = new JsonRest({
        target: 'https://api.xxx.com/data',
        headers: {
            "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + 'd4c72611fc43ab44a46344d907a2b96964df2c91',
            "X-Requested-With": null`, // no prefligh
            "If-None-Match": null // solve my issue
        }
    });
    store.get('1-00').then(function (data) {
        // ok works here
        console.log('get', data)
    });
    // post request
    store.add({name:'test'}).then(function (data) {
        // ok works here
        console.log('add', data)
    });
```